# Python Error: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 16: given 14

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine the columns from 2 dataframes into one dataframe so I can build training and test samples. I'm using the walkthough at this link [Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-hospital-readmission-for-patients-with-diabetes-using-scikit-learn-a2e359b15f0) but I'm using a different excel spreadsheet.

So far all the code has worked until I try to combine the columns of the two data frames. The code is below is a trimmed down version of what I have so far, but I believe all the code that I left out was just exploring the data. All that said, I'm pretty new on my Python journey, so I'm not sure how much code would be beneficial, so I can post more if I need to.

All the code works except for the last line, which gives me this error: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 16: given 14

Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

healthcare = pd.read_csv('/medical_clean.csv')

cols_cat_num = ['ReAdmis', 'Initial_admin', 'HighBlood', 'Stroke', 'Complication_risk', 'Overweight', 'Arthritis', 'Diabetes', 'BackPain', 'Anxiety', 'Allergic_rhinitis', 'Reflux_esophagitis', 'Asthma']
healthcare[cols_cat_num] = healthcare[cols_cat_num].astype('str')

healthcare_cat=pd.get_dummies(healthcare[cols_cat_num + ['HighBlood']], drop_first = True)

healthcare_num=['Population', 'VitD_levels', 'Income', 'Doc_visits', 'Full_meals_eaten', 'vitD_supp', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4', 'Item5', 'Item6', 'Item7', 'Item8']

healthcare[healthcare_num]= healthcare[healthcare_num].astype('str')

finalhealth= healthcare_num + healthcare_cat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`healthcare_cat` is a pandas DataFrame while `healthcare_num` is a list. The error message is a result of not being able to perform the addition using these two very different objects, though Python tried to "coerce".

You could explore `pd.concat()` to combine DataFrames.